# Symbol in Theorem A.1.1 in Durrett's Probability (4th edition)

Tags: measure-theory, semialgebras

The highlighted symbol is found in Durrett's "Probability: Theory and Examples" (4th edition).[image]

What does it mean?

Comment: Looks like a misprint for $\bigcup_{i\ge1}$.

Comment: The author defines "+" in this context as disjoint union (see the top of page 4).

Comment: @quasi, is this definition explicit in somewhere in the book?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$